# Can I access a local variable of a function without outputting it?

Tags: matlab, variables

I have a function in MATALB that looks like the following:

```
function [a, b] = SumIt(I1, I2)

    a = sum(I1);
    b = sum(I2);
    c = sum(I1/I2);

end
```

In the command window, I run the function but I cannot access the `c` variable. I know that I can do something like this `[a, b, c] = SumIt(I1, I2)` and access `c` variable. Can I access the variable `c` without outputting it?

The issue is that I have many outputs that are useless but I need to access them. How can I do this?

I tried with `global` but I got the same error.

```
function [a, b] = SumIt(I1, I2)
    global c;

    a = sum(I1);
    b = sum(I2);
    c = sum(I1/I2);

end
>> [a, b] = SumIt([1 4 6], [1 2 3]);
>> c
Undefined function or variable 'c'.
```

Comment: Declare `c` to be global to the base workspace by executing `global c` at the command prompt. In general, you have to decalre the variable to be global in all workspaces in order to access it. See `help global` and the supporting docs for examples. Also, besides `global`, you can use the `assignin` function. See `help assignin` for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that this can be done is to have a function script that also declares `SumIt` as an additional function and also declaring `c` to be `global` outside of the scope of `SumIt`.  Consider the following test function shown below:

```
function [] = test_func()

global c;

function [a, b] = SumIt(I1, I2)        
    a = sum(I1);
    b = sum(I2);
    c = sum(I1/I2);    
end

[t1, t2] = SumIt(6, 3);
disp(['t1 = ' num2str(t1)]);
disp(['t2 = ' num2str(t2)]);
disp(['c = ' num2str(c)]);

end
```

I have created a test function called `test_func` where we declare `c` to be `global`, but it is **outside** of the scope of `SumIt`.  After, I declare `SumIt` as a nested function, then try and call it with some example numbers.  I then display the outputs of `SumIt` as well as `c`.  Since `I1 = 6, I2 = 3`, we should get `c = 2`.

This is what I get when I run `test_func`:

```
>> test_func

t1 = 6
t2 = 3
c = 2
```

## Minor note

It looks like `I1` and `I2` are vectors judging from the context of your use with `sum`.  As such, you should probably consider using the element-by-element division operator `./` if what I am interpreting is correct.  Are you trying to divide each element of `I1` by `I2` and then summing the result?  If that's the case, you need to change your function such that it becomes:

```
function [a, b] = SumIt(I1, I2)        
    a = sum(I1);
    b = sum(I2);
    c = sum(I1./I2);
end
```

Comment: The `assignin` function would also work in at least some cases.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Hmm! Never used that before. Thanks!